# 'object' não contém uma definição para 'Action'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou usando MVC 5 com Identity para login, apareceu este erro que até agora não consegui achar uma solução.

Erro acontece na view `_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está provavelmente no local em que é feita a chamada da partial view, que está passando um objeto que não possui a propriedade `Action` para a view `_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml`.

Provavelmente em sua `_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml` você está recebendo um model `dynamic` assim:

```
@model dynamic
```

E fazendo referencia à propriedade `Model.Action`, sendo que a propriedade `Action` não existe no objeto que você está passando do seu controller para a sua partial-view.

```
return View(objeto_que_nao_possui_action);
```

ou

```
 @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", objeto_que_nao_possui_action)
```

Sendo que `objeto_que_nao_possui_action` é o objeto a ser investigado.